# Estimate for functions in the domain of the Laplacian on closed interval and relative boundedness of multiplication wrt Laplacian.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ be the Laplacian on the line(compact interval) with
$D(A) = \{f \in H^2([0,1]) | f(0)=f(1)=0\} \subset L^2([0,1])$, where
$H^2([0,1]) = \{f \in L^2([0,1]): f,f' \in AC([0,1]), f',f'' \in L^2([0,1])\}$
($f,f'$ are absolutely continuous).

1) I want to show for every $\varepsilon > 0$ the estimate $\|f\|^2_\infty \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \|f''\|^2_2 + \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} \|f\|^2_2$

Now, since $f$ is absolutely continuous, we have: $f(x) = \int^x_0 f'(t) dt$ and therefore for $x \in [0,1]$: $|f(x)|^2 \leq \int^1_0  |f'(t)|^2 dt$.
By integration of parts, this integral equals
$- \int^1_0 f''(t) \overline {f(t)} dt$. In turn one could apply Cauchy-Schwarz to see that $|f(x)|^2 \leq \|f''\|_2 \cdot \|f\|_2$.
I do not see how to proceed from here.

2) Assuming the estimate 1) is shown, i want to deduce that the multiplication operator with $q \in L^2([0,1])$ has relative bound $0$ w.r.t. $A$. Now for $f\in D(A)$ we have $\|q f\|^2_2 \leq \|q\|^2_2 \|f\|^2_2 \leq \|q\|^2_2 \|f\|^2_\infty \leq \|q\|^2_2(\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \|f''\|^2_2 + \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} \|f\|^2_2)$ and therefore $\|q f\|_2 \leq \|q\|_2(\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}} \|f''\|_2 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon}} \|f\|_2)$ for all $\varepsilon$ which shows that the relative bound is $0$. Is this argumentation ok? (seems a bit inelegant).

Comment: For $a,b \ge 0$, $2ab \le a^{2}+b^{2}$. Replace $a$ by $\sqrt{\varepsilon}a$ and $b$ by $b/\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. The second part looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

As TrialAndError said, the proof of part 1 is finished by using the [Peter-Paul inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Elementary_case) 
$$ab\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}a^2 + \frac{1}{2\epsilon} b^2$$
where in your case, $a=\|f''\|$ and $b=\|f\|$.

The second part is correct, and I don't see anything inelegant there: this is how one estimates things by using *a little bit* of higher derivatives.